# How can I make a track for an object in Blender Game (not blender render)?

Tags: game-engine, tracking

I want to do a track in blender game. I have done it in blender render with constraints track to,... but it's not working in blender game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Edit Object Actuator and set it to "Track to". Set the Object you want to track to in the Object Picker and choose the track axis. If you pick x it will point with the x axis to the object to track etc. If you want the object to rotate only around the z axis, don't enable 3d. If you want every axis, enable 3d. UP axis should usually stay z if you didn't rotate your object in a strange way (it means z will point up).

[image]
Suzanne tracks to the cube on the y axis

[image]
with 3D enabled she also lifts her head for it.

Comment: You'll also want true level triggering enabled. With your current setup, Suzanne will track to the cube during the one tick when the game starts, and then not again after that.